# Button in a popover will display text in the main view controller

Tags: objective-c, uipopovercontroller

My popover has a button which when clicked, will display a text in the main view controller.

Here's my code for the button:

```
- (IBAction)print:(UIButton *)sender {
   self.displayText.text= @"Hello World";
}
```

By the way, I followed the tutorial [here](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/ipad-development/presenting-a-popover-in-ipad/).

I tried to run the program and I'm getting this error when I click the "print hello world" button:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PopoverViewController
>   print:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe379240'

I thought that when it's a button in popover, it's a different case. And i've followed few solutions to this problem (posted also by people who encountered the same problem) already but i can't seem to solve it. Still having errors. Hope you could help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the action for the message, you need to send the message to your View Controller instead of to your Popover.

Which you can't really do when you have them in separate xib's.

There are a few different ways of approaching this, one of which would be to implement a delegate in your popover class, and when you create the popover set the delegate to self (the view controller which created it) and implement the delegate method.  Then, when you press the button, it calls a function **in your popover class** which then calls your delegate's method.

Comment: Thanks! It's really helpful. I will try it now on my program.